# Chromium always starts as floating in awesome.wm

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, awesome-wm

I'm using awesome as window manager for a small surf&info terminal. Chromium is started directly after login on the first workspace and should be displayed fullscreen. I've set the layout of all workspaces to `awful.layout.suit.max` and followed [Awesome FAQ](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_start_clients_on_specific_tags_and_others_as_floating.3F) so that Chromium and all other (automatically) started programs will be shown on the right workspace. All programs except Chromium will start correctly in fullscreen mode.

I tried

```
{ rule = { class = "chromium-browser" },  
    properties = {floating = false, tag = tags[1][1]}}
```

and

```
{ rule = { class = "chromium-browser" },  properties = {tag = tags[1][1]}}
```

but Chromium will always start in floating mode. This is a bit annoying as you still see awesome's panel at the top.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to run `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` and then click a chromium window. This will return the correct class string.

Don't forget to restart AwesomeWM after you make this change.

Comment: This reports `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "chromium-browser", "Chromium-browser"` on Gentoo (where I develop) and `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "chromium", "Chromium"` on Debian (which the destination machine runs). Adding the same rule with `class="chromium"` did help. A bit weird that the name differs between Linux distributions.

Comment: @xhochy I believe that package builders of some distributions use chromium-browser to differentiate the executable from the one provided by the game [Chromium BSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_B.S.U.). I assume they changed the WM_CLASS appropriately.